# jmeter thread group not running all users

Tags: jmeter

I am running a recorded test plan. I have assigned 5 diferents users in the Thread Group, with a Ramp-up Period of 5 and Loop Count of 1.

This is what happens:

Start the test.

The test runs without errors and it seems that the 5 users are execute correctly when I check in the View Results Tree but when I check in the system only 2 or 3 users are registrated. I delete the registrated users and run the script again and again 2 or 3 users are registrated (some times are not the same) of the 5 users.

I don't understand what can possibly do that my test behave like that...
Why does my test plan not run for the 5 users?

I've checked the resources being utilized on my machine but they were fine, no problems with that.

The log of the Jmeter is the follow:

```
2015/01/23 12:54:11 INFO  - jmeter.util.BSFTestElement: Registering JMeter version of JavaScript engine as work-round for BSF-22 
2015/01/23 12:54:12 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Cannot find .className property for htmlParser, using default 
2015/01/23 12:54:12 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is  
2015/01/23 12:54:12 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is  
2015/01/23 12:54:12 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is  
2015/01/23 12:54:12 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is  
2015/01/23 12:54:12 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser 
2015/01/23 12:54:12 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.WebServiceSamplerGui 
2015/01/23 12:54:12 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.modifier.gui.ParamModifierGui 
2015/01/23 12:54:12 INFO  - jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\keytool' 
2015/01/23 12:54:12 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file E:\Pruebas no Funcionales\JMeter\apache-jmeter-2.12\apache-jmeter-2.12\bin\proxyserver.jks 
2015/01/23 12:54:12 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times 
2015/01/23 12:54:12 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1 
2015/01/23 12:54:12 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true 
2015/01/23 12:54:12 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000 
2015/01/23 12:54:54 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='E:\Pruebas no Funcionales\JMeter\apache-jmeter-2.12\apache-jmeter-2.12\bin' 
2015/01/23 12:54:54 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: E:\Pruebas no Funcionales\JMeter\JMScripts\Solicitud_Credito.jmx 
2015/01/23 12:54:54 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='E:\Pruebas no Funcionales\JMeter\JMScripts' 
2015/01/23 12:54:54 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2 
2015/01/23 12:54:54 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8 
2015/01/23 12:54:54 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 2.7 
2015/01/23 12:54:54 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file version 1618048 
2015/01/23 12:54:54 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: All converter versions present and correct 
2015/01/23 12:54:54 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager: Settings: Delete null: true Check: false Allow variable: true Save: true Prefix:  
2015/01/23 12:54:55 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='E:\Pruebas no Funcionales\JMeter\JMScripts' 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Listeners will be started after enabling running version 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: To revert to the earlier behaviour, define jmeterengine.startlistenerslater=false 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Carga_Usuarios 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Carga_Usuarios. 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=true 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: jmeterthread.startearlier=true (see jmeter.properties) 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Running PostProcessors in forward order 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Carga_Usuarios 1-1 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Stored: Filecnx.csv 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHCAbstractImpl: Local host = CONSULT0002 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: HTTP request retry count = 0 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Setting up HTTPS TrustAll scheme 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager: Using default SSL protocol: TLS 
2015/01/23 12:55:06 INFO  - jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager: SSL session context: per-thread 
2015/01/23 12:55:56 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Carga_Usuarios 1-1 
2015/01/23 12:55:56 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Carga_Usuarios 1-1 
2015/01/23 12:55:56 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2015/01/23 12:55:56 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Close: Filecnx.csv
2015/01/23 12:55:56 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

If you need any other information, please let me know...
thank you !

Comment: put the full log, is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer to this problem. It wasn't any problem with the script was a conflict between the data that was sending related to the city and the town. The script was sending a fix value of the city and the town belong of that city.

When the city was different it wasn't a problem because the combobox included all the citys but when the town was different, the script was inserted a value that it doesn't exist in the town combobox so it shows an error validation that stop the flow of that user but it didn't show any error in the JMeter. 
So when the users had the same city and town, they were inserted but if they didn't it shows no error but was not inserted in the DB.